# MSP430 UART receiving a string - TX problem

Tags: c, microcontroller, uart, msp430

Using MSP430F6736A embedded programming. Code written in Code Composer Studio. I have a problem in my code, but i have no idea what i can do to fix it.
When I compile the program in code composer, works well but UART are sending to PC just ".ø€.ø€.€€x" that means i'm getting only strange charracters

```
#include "msp430g2553.h"
#include <stdio.h>

float RLDR=0, lux=0, v0=0;
unsigned int ADC10_vetor[16]={0};
unsigned int sum=0;
unsigned char i=0;
unsigned char TX_data[32], tx_index = 0, lux_int =0;


void ini_ucon(void);
void ini_p1_p2(void);
void ini_Timer0(void);
void ini_ADC10(void);
void ini_USCI_UART(void);


void ini_ucon(void){
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
DCOCTL = CALDCO_8MHZ;
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_8MHZ;
BCSCTL2 = DIVS0 + DIVS1;  //SMCLK = 1MHz
__enable_interrupt();
}

void ini_p1_p2(void){
    P1DIR = 0xFF;
    P1OUT = 0x00;
    P2DIR = 0xFF;
    P2OUT = 0x00;
}


void ini_Timer0(void){
    TA0CTL = TASSEL1 + ID1 + ID0 + MC0;   //SMCLK = 1MHz/8 = 125000
    TA0CCTL1 = OUTMOD0 + OUTMOD1 + OUTMOD2 + OUT;
    TA0CCR0 = 62499; //2Hz = 0.5 secs. , TA0CCR0 = 0.5*125000 - 1 = 62499
    TA0CCR1 = 31249; //PWM = 50%
}

void ini_ADC10(void){
     ADC10CTL0 = ADC10SHT1 + MSC + ADC10ON + ADC10IE;
     ADC10CTL1 = INCH0 + INCH2 + SHS0 + ADC10SSEL1 +  CONSEQ1;
     ADC10AE0 = BIT5; //P1.5 para A5
     ADC10DTC0 = 0;
     ADC10DTC1 = 16;
ADC10SA = &ADC10_vetor[0];
     ADC10CTL0 |= ENC;
}

int main(void){
    ini_ucon();
    ini_p1_p2();
    ini_Timer0();
    ini_ADC10();
    ini_USCI_UART();

    while(1){
    }
}

#pragma vector=ADC10_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC10_RTI(void){
ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;
soma = 0;
for(i=0;i<16;i++){
    sum = sum + ADC10_vetor[i];
}
sum = sum >> 4;
    //RLDR = (42625000)/(3*sum)-10000;
    //lux = 500/(RLDR/1000);
    //v0=5*(sum/(sum+10000));

    v0=sum*(3.6/1024);
    RLDR = (10000*(5-v0))/v0;
    lux = (500/(RLDR/1000));
    lux_int = (unsigned char) lux;
    sprintf(&TX_data[0], "LUX = %d \n", lux_int);
    UCA0TXBUF = TX_data[0];
          tx_index++;

    ADC10SA = &ADC10_vetor[0];
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC; 

}

#pragma vector=USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void RTI_USCI_UART(void)
{
    IFG2 &= ~UCA0TXIFG;

    if(TX_data[tx_index] == '\0'){
        tx_index = 0;
    }else{
        if(tx_index >= 32){
            tx_index = 0;
        }else{
            UCA0TXBUF = TX_data[tx_index];
            tx_index++;
        }
    }
}

void ini_USCI_UART(void){

    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;

    UCA0CTL0 = 0;

    UCA0CTL1 = UCSSEL0 + UCSSEL1 + UCSWRST;

    UCA0BR0 = 0xA0;
    UCA0BR1 = 0x01;

    UCA0MCTL = UCBRS1 + UCBRS2;

    UCA0STAT = 0;

    P1SEL |= BIT2;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT2;

    UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;

    IFG2 &= ~UCA0TXIFG;
    IE2 |= UCA0TXIE;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you check the correct baudrate on your PC?

Comment: what does it look like on a scope?  very possible that the receiver is synced up on the wrong start bit

Comment: or that your timing is too close to the margin, what are you running the msp430 at and what baud rate for the uart

Comment: and what are you using to receive it on the other end?

Comment: I assume you did it with polling first long before using an interrupt?  did you have the same problems with polling?

Comment: Are you getting "some" correct characters from the UART and "some" corrupt, or "all" corrupt? It sounds like you may not have the Data Stop and Parity bits for your serial device set correctly. (if you have other programs that work just fine with the current settings, then that is unlikely). Here is a helpful article [Serial Communication using MSP430 UART(USCI_A)](https://www.xanthium.in/Serial-Communication-MSP430-UART-USCI_A) which contains a Baud Ratee `UCBRx` and `UCBRSx` table for various configurations.